# What is the name for this relationship between a 1-form and a vector?

Tags: terminology, differential-forms, covariance, exterior-algebra, exterior-derivative

all.
I have a question about Visual Differential Geometry and Forms - A Mathematical Drama in Five Acts (by Tristan Needham).

This book shows two relationships between Forms and vector. And I have a question on the second one.

The first one is a relationship between a 2-form $\Psi$ and a vector $\Psi$(underlined), which is shown as (34.10) on page p377. Their corresponding components are equal, that is, $\Psi^i$ = $\Psi$(underlined)$_i$. This relationship is called Hodge (star) duality operator.
[image]

The second one is a relationship between a 1-form $\phi$ and a vector $\phi$(underlined), which is shown as (34.14) on page p379. Their corresponding components are equal, that is, $\phi_i$ = $\phi$(underlined)$_i$.
[image]

My question is: What is the name for this second relationship?

P.S. This second relationship is so natural that it deserves a name, right?

Comment: Congrats on getting all the way to the end :)

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom, thanks for your concise answer which you deleted, that is, it is an isomorphism between $V$ and $V^∗$.  I should not forget this fact.

Comment: Yeah. In the actual mathematical practice, stuff is much more complicated than what Needham makes it out to be, but that ideas sticks for now. By the way, I've pretty much went through this book about 4-5 months ago, if you want help, feel free to conact using the info I put on profile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given any finite dimensional vector space $V$ over a field $k$, and a choice of basis $e_1,\dots,e_n$, there is a canonical isomorphism $\alpha\colon V\cong V^*$, where $V^*$ is the dual vector space to $V$, i.e., the vector space of linear maps $V\to k$. (Linear maps $V\to k$ are also called one-forms.)

The isomorphism $\alpha$ is defined by sending the vector $e_i$ to the one-form $e^i$ (note the superscript) defined on a vector $v = v_1e_1 + \dots + v_ne_n$ by
$$
e^i(v) = e^i(v_1e_1 + \dots + v_ne_n) = v_i.
$$
In other words, $e^i$ just returns the $i$th component of the vector $v$. You should check that the one-forms $e^1,e^2,\dots,e^n$ form a basis for $V^*$. This basis is known as **the corresponding dual basis** for $V^*$. This is all linear algebra, but in differential geometry, this isomorphism is a simple version of the [*musical isomorphism*](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Musical_isomorphism), which is the more general term for the isomorphism between the tangent and cotangent bundles of a manifold.

In the example in Needham's book, if we choose the standard basis $\mathbf e_1,\mathbf e_2,\mathbf e_3$ for $\mathbb R^3$, then the one-forms $dx^1,dx^2,dx^3$ are precisely the corresponding dual basis for $(\mathbb R^3)^*$.